# Is local_variables_initializer really necessary?

Tags: python, tensorflow, initializer

In practice, isn't running `global_variables_initializer` enough to initialize model variables?

`local_variables_initializer` seems to be unnecessary and absent even in official and semi-official tensorflow example code. See for example:

- https://github.com/dandelionmane/tf-dev-summit-tensorboard-tutorial
- https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros

In both cases only `global_variables_initializer` is used.

Am I missing something here? Is there any case where I should call `local_variables_initializer` explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

`local_variables_initializer` is useful in particular for streaming metrics (e.g. `tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_auc`). As said in the doc of [contrib.metrics](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/contrib.metrics):

> Because the streaming metrics use local variables, the Initialization stage is performed by running the op returned by `tf.local_variables_initializer()`.